# In finite groups does counting orders of elements is enough to determine if they are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Three finite groups with the same numbers of elements of each order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62331/three-finite-groups-with-the-same-numbers-of-elements-of-each-order)

Suppose that we have two finite groups $G$ and $H$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\left|\left\{ g\in G:\text{ord}\left(g\right)=n\right\} \right|=\left|\left\{ h\in H:\text{ord}\left(h\right)=n\right\} \right|$$
meaning, the number of elements of order $n$ in each group is equal.
Does that imply that they are isomorphic?
(With abelian groups I think it is true and easily deduced from the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups)

Comment: No: eg  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62331/three-finite-groups-with-the-same-numbers-of-elements-of-each-order

Comment: What a disappointment. I always thought this was true and I just waited for a day when I knew enough group theory to be able to prove it!

Comment: Why is this a disappointment? It tells you that groups are too interesting to be captured by an invariant as boring as order profile!

Comment: @Qiaochu: It isn't disappointment as a fact itself, I agree with your statement, but it is disappointing due to my expectation!

Comment: Interesting example. Thank you.